# What’s wrong with my rosemary?

Tags: rosemary

My rosemary is inherited from the previous house owners. It lives in the backyard in NY, but I am under the impression it should still be green in winter? It’s this pale sickly color with a purplish tint[image]. Can anyone tell me what’s wrong with it and if/how I can fix it?

Comment: I'm next to part of NY, and while rosemary can be planted out for the summer, it needs to be dug up and brought inside to survive the winter. I would guess the same applies where you are (or possibly other winter strategies like piling several feet of leaves or straw over it in fall, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

By the look of it, I think your plant has suffered from frostbite.

Also, as you mentioned that it is purplish, it means the plant lacks fertilizer.

Rosemary loves full sun, you can put it inside in winters under artificial light and take it outside whenever the day is sunny.